# timedatectl not get update via curl request via cronjobs

Tags: server, apache2, php, cron, curl

I have time problem on Ubuntu 20.04

When I command time : `timedatectl` System clock synchronized: yes,

but when I request time in PHP via curl the time not being change,
`https://domain.com/time.php`

but If I add some rnd parameter in same URL time get update every seconds.
`https://domain.com/time.php?action=time&rnd=$rnd`

time.php is just a test file, I have many php curl request file, so I want fix it for globally on the server

> ```
> include /home/admin/conf/web/domain.com/nginx.hsts.conf*;
>
> # protect videos from direct access
> location ^~ /contents/videos/ {
>     root /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html;
>     limit_rate_after 2m;
>     expires        35d;
>     internal;
> }
>
> location ^~ /contents/albums/ {
>     root /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html;
>     expires        35d;
> }
>
> location / {
>     proxy_pass      https://0.0.0.0:8443;
>
>     proxy_cache cache;
>     proxy_cache_valid 15m;
>     proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
>     proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
>     proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
>     proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session $http_x_update;
>
>     location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|g>
>         proxy_cache    off;
>         root           /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html;
>         access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.log combined;
>         access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes;
>         expires        35d;
>         try_files      $uri @fallback;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a long list of file extensions for which you disable caching, but php is not one of them. So when you request time.php the page is cached on NGINX for 15 minutes.

When you add the query string parameters, you are changing the URL, so nginx gets a new copy and caches that too. Each change in the $rnd value will get a fresh copy.

**Update from comments (map)**

```
# Cache bypass 
map $http_cookie $no_cache { 
  default $no_cache_path; 
  ~SESS 1; 
  ~wordpress_logged_in 1; 
}

map $uri $no_cache_path {
  default 0;
  ~*time.php 1;
}
```

This will bypass cache if the cookie is set, if it isn't it'll check the $no_cache_path map which bypasses time.php

Comment: Hi, How I can disable cache for php

Comment: somwhere in your config you probably have a section which sets $no_cache? You could use a map... like this:

Comment: I have `    # Cache bypass
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }`

Comment: can you please add an example to answer `# Cache bypass map $http_cookie $no_cache { default 0; ~SESS 1; ~wordpress_logged_in 1; }`

Comment: time.php is just a test file, I have many php files which make **curl request via cronjob,** so I want fix it for globally on the server

Comment: Then change `~*time.php` to `~*.php` and it wont cache any PHP files at all.

Comment: already changed and cleared cache but still same time

Comment: Are you testing with curl or your web browser? You browser could have cached the page. The example map should work. If it's not then the config you've posted may not be the config that's handling these requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124289/discussion-between-mitra-and-tuxinvader).